# How can I deselect checkbox when matching more than one || in a statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdown list that will select checkboxes based on the value of the dropdown list.  It works fine except I can't figure out what i'm missing to unselect checkboxes when the values aren't matched.

For instance, if I choose A, CheckBox2 and CheckBox4 are selected which is correct.  Now when I choose "Select A Letter", CheckBox2 and CheckBox4 are still selected even though the value 9 is not equal to 1 or 2 or 3.

Now if I select C, CheckBox1, CheckBox2 and CheckBox3 are selected and if I choose anything other than C, CheckBox1 is deselected which is what I want.  It seems like there is an issue when i'm using || more than once in a statement.

JS:

```
 <script>
 function setCheckBox1(value) {
       var chk1 = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox1.ClientID %>");
       var chk2 = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox2.ClientID %>");
       var chk3 = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox3.ClientID %>");
       var chk4 = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox4.ClientID %>");
       var chk5 = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox5.ClientID %>");
  chk1.checked = (value == '3');
  chk2.checked = (value == '1' || '2' || '3');
  chk3.checked = (value == '0');
  chk4.checked = (value == '1' || '2' || '3');
  chk5.checked = (value == '0');
}
</script>
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" onchange="setCheckBox1(this.value);">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">Choose Letter</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">A</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">B/<asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">C</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">D</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="5">E</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="6">F</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="7">G</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="8">H</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
```

Comment: `(value == '1' || value =='2' || value =='3')`, You need to compare individually

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!